# Why multiple docker containers can have the same internal port

Tags: docker

Consider this two `docker container run` commands:

```
docker container run --publish 89:80 ImageFoo
docker container run --publish 90:80 ImageBoo
```

Why multiple docker container can have the same **right** port?

Comment: because the containers are isolated from each other therefore the internal port is only reachable from published one

Comment: Hey @LinPy, not sure I understand, what do you mean by isolated from each other, and how does it make the internal port to be reachable only from published one?

Comment: the hole idea from container that you have a isolated environment , so container one cant see what internal ports container two has. to make it rechable you need to use the published port (the right port). and right  it makes the internal port to be reachable only from published one

Comment: If you are interested in learning about how this isolation works, it's a linux thing and it's called "namespaces". Docker is using network namespaces to do all this magic. For more details, you can start looking at https://docker-k8s-lab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docker/netns.html or https://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2016/04/10/network-namespaces/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port on the right, is inside the container. Each container has its own virtual network adapter, thus you are able to use the whole port range independently.

Comment: Unlike the host who has one virtual network adapter